# Phoneme from Jsonstream unrecognized in c#

Tags: c#, azure-functions, text-to-speech, ssml, phoneme

I have a little problem with my JsonStream in C#

I am reading a Json Blob in my Storage with this inside:

```
{"id":"275177", "fremdwort":"1.FFC-Frankfurt", "ipa":"ʹeːɐ̯stɐ ɛf ɛf ʦeː ʹfraŋkfʊrt"}
```

in C#:

```
 while (Jsonreader.Read())
                        { if (Jsonreader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                            {
                                var record = serializer.Deserialize<JsonClass>(Jsonreader);
                                log.LogInformation(record.Id.ToString() +" , "+ record.Fremdwort +" , "+ record.Ipa);
```

If I log my JsonStreamer I receive this:

```
[2021-03-04T13:30:51.367Z] 275177 , 1.FFC-Frankfurt , ´e???st? ?f ?f ?e? ´fra?kf?rt
```

I am missing something to encode this questionmarks, What would be the solution to receive the right string without the ???.

Thank you stranger !

Comment: Where did you see the `??` ? These appear only when trying to read *non-Unicode* strings using the wrong codepage, or trying to display text in a console using the wrong codepage. NET strings are Unicode, so the problem is either the original blog or the way you display the output

Comment: BTW theres' no if or but about this. This question proves it: StackOverflow is a .NET application. If there was a problem with Unicode, your own question would be mangled.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos heyhey, I am seeing the ?? in the debug console. So it means only the console cant display it but the symbols are right the reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is a serious problem. I test it in my side, and the mess code `???` only occur when we run the function in Visual Studio in local. And it just shows in logs. If we output it in `responseMessage`(like below screenshot), it will not show `???` in output.

[image]

[image]

And if we run the function on azure portal, it also will not show mess code `???`. No matter in logs or in output.
[image]

So we do not need to worry about that, the mess code `???` show in local logs may caused by coding problem of logs console.

Comment: Heyhey thank you for the Effort :) , yeah I wrote the rows into a Table Storage and everything was fine in the end. Just a problem with the console in vs.